# How to set fetchSize for concrete query?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to set fetchSize only for one query and I can't find appropriate api for that.

my code looks like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowCallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {...}
);
```

How can I pass fetchSize to the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `PreparedStatementSetter` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html))
Given the query

```
select * from mytable where user_id > ?
```

You can use

```
jdbcTemplate.query(query, 
    new PreparedStatementSetter() {
       @Override
       public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
           ps.setInt(1, userId);
           ps.setFetchSize(500);
       }
    }, 
    new RowCallbackHandler() {
       @Override
       public void processRow(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
         ...
       }
    });
```

Or in a more compact form

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
      query, 
      ps -> { 
         ps.setInt(1, userId);
         ps.setFetchSize(500);
      },
      rs -> { ... }
);
```

Keep in mind that

> Implementations are responsible for setting any necessary parameters.
>   SQL with placeholders will already have been supplied.

---

For a single resulting object, use the

```
public <T> T query(String sql,
                   PreparedStatementSetter pss,
                   ResultSetExtractor<T> rse) throws DataAccessException;
```

method. For example

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
    query,
    new ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter(new Object[] {balanceId}),
    rs -> {
       final String field1 = rs.getString("field1");
       // Get other fields and construct the resulting object
       return new YourClass(field1, ...);
    }
);
```

Comment: It looks perfect!

Comment: @gstackoverflow The thing is I've never seen a tutorial which uses it. That's why it is so "hidden" inside the documentation.

Comment: @gstackoverflow btw, remember you need to set values manually.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @gstackoverflow for example if you have a placeholder in the "where" clause, you need to manually set its value using the "ps" variable Spring gives you. That's the trade-off. Answer updated

Comment: @gstackoverflow how are you passing that argument now to the query method? It seems you aren't.

Comment: I used another method: jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?",
                new Object[]{balanceId},
                MyTableMapper.INSTANCE
        );

Comment: @gstackoverflow ok, let me come up with an updated answer.

Comment: I am trying **new ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter(new Object[]{id}) {...}** instead of  **new PreparedStatementSetter**

Comment: @gstackoverflow seems fine to me! However you should also switch from RowCallbackHandler to ResultSetExtractor, as you're dealing with a single row.

Comment: @gstackoverflow this is the right query method to use https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I need RowCallbackHandler because my select could return millions of rows

Comment: @gstackoverflow what do you mean? I'm still editing

Comment: I am about my suggestion

Comment: @gstackoverflow but queryForObject returns only a single one, are you sure you're using it now? I say that because you wrote "I used another method: queryForObject". So I'm a bit lost now

Comment: I just wanted to show API example I use. actually I used this.jdbcTemplate.query(
                    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time> ? AND color = ?",
                    new Object[]{date, color},
                    MyTableMapper.INSTANCE
            )

Comment: @gstackoverflow ahh okay!

Comment: Your advice ps.setInt(1, userId) is helpful for me. Thank you for your efforts